# What video resolution is best?

Tags: video, resolution, mp4, avi

I shot video's on my Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge (in vertical mode, not landscape) and paid no mind to what the video resolution was. I then converted the mp4 videos to avi and burnt them to dvd disc but when i watch the video's on my widescreen tv the top and the bottom of the video is out of shot. I tried altering the aspect ratio on my tv but it made no difference. Now i have a program on my laptop that converts video's to all formats, It works great but i have no idea what resolution to convert them to so all of the video is on the tv screen & not just the middle! Please can someone help me? What resolution is best to watch phone-made video's on a widescreen tv? Thanks.

Comment: Check the resolution of your TV and try to crop to that one, or at least to a resolution with the same ratio.

Comment: Andi, you should really watch this video (it's not a serious video, but it's message is absolutely correct, human eyes are horizontal and thefore video should be too). In the future, just never make vertical video's. youtube.com/watch?v=Bt9zSfinwFA . You mightl need some video-editing software to fix the video. Do you have some software? If not, I will try and find a free solution.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that there is no proper solution to make your video look good. It went wrong during the shooting of the video. In the future, never film vertically and you should have no problems at all.

There are three options:

- You can stretch the video (which looks bad)
- You crop the video, getting rid of part of the top and/or part of the bottom of the video (you already effectively did this and it didn't give you what you wanted)
- Project part of the video to the sides of the screen. Then you have the full vertical video in the middle (horizontally) of the screen. This video shows how you can do it, but you'd need software: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LdCLQ2DQ0NY

As for the resolution, match the vertical resolution and horizontal resolution of the final video to that of the DVD standard(720x480 for PAL or 720x576 for NTSC) If your player can play both standards, use the one matching your TV bast (assuming a widescreen TV, that'll be PAL). You can choose to fill up the side of the video with black until you match the resolution, or like I said before with a blurred version of part of the video (example image below).

[image]

Comment: Fine, except that DVD resolution is either 720x480 NTSC or 720x576 PAL, so that ought to be your maximum resolution, whatever resolution the screen is.

Comment: Good point, I'll change my answer accordingly.

Comment: You forgot: turn the video and the TV ☺